# How to convert an Image to base64 string in java?

Tags: java, image, base64

It may be a duplicate but i am facing some problem to convert the image into `Base64` for sending it for `Http Post`. I have tried this code but it gave me wrong encoded string.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

           File f =  new File("C:/Users/SETU BASAK/Desktop/a.jpg");
             String encodstring = encodeFileToBase64Binary(f);
             System.out.println(encodstring);
       }

       private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file){
            String encodedfile = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                encodedfile = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes).toString();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return encodedfile;
        }
```

**Output:** [B@677327b6 
 
But i converted this same image into `Base64` in many online encoders and they all gave the correct big Base64 string.

**Edit:** How is it a duplicate?? The link which is duplicate of mine doesn't give me solution of converting the string what i wanted.

**What am i missing here??**

Comment: How are you determining that this be the incorrect base 64 string?

Comment: as  online encoders are returning big strings of base64

Comment: Can you provide code for the POST method ? I'm in the same problem ( post an image ... ) Thanks!!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the `toString()` of the call to `Base64.encodeBase64(bytes)` which returns a byte array. So what you get in the end is the default string representation of a byte array, which corresponds to the output you get.

Instead, you should do:

```
encodedfile = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: That solved my issue

Comment: String strBase64=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0)

Answer (score 18):

I think you might want:

```
String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Comment: import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; I am importing this.. here Base64 doesn't have getEncoder() like things

Comment: @setubasak it is about `java.util.Base64` added in Java 8.

Answer (score 7):

this did it for me. you can vary the options for the output format to Base64.Default whatsoever.

```
// encode base64 from image
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Comment: where to feed my image file??

Comment: here, it is loaded into imageBitmap.  method .compress converts and encodes it into baos

Comment: Base64.URL_SAFE these are not working for me?? what is to import??

Comment: sorry, i just noticed this is not about android. I will look up for a working solution