# JAXRS response with multiple file

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, rest, jersey-2.0

I am able to send a single image file to ReactJS. But I have to send multiple image files to ReactJS.

JAXRS code:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/download/file1")
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM )
    public Response getFile() {
        String fileName = DOWNLOAD_FILE_SERVER+"BMI/testcases/Basispath_BMI_0_out.gif";
        File file = new File( fileName);
        System.out.println("fileName inside getFile = "+fileName);
        final String filename = "testcase1.gif"; 
        System.out.println("filename inside getFile = "+filename);

        // Create the JAXRS response
        // Don't forget to include the filename in 2 HTTP headers: 
        //
        // a) The standard 'Content-Disposition' one, and
        // b) The custom 'X-Suggested-Filename'  

        final Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(
                file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("X-Actual-Content-Length", file.length())
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
       
        // All Done.
        return builder.build();
    }
```

ReactJS code:

```
downloadImage = () => {  
        axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:9900/EXAMPLE/rest/myresource/download/file1',
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob',             
          }).then((response) => {
              const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
              const link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = url;             
              var filename = 'Image1.gif'              
              link.setAttribute('download', filename);
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
              document.body.removeChild(link);              
          })
          .catch((response) => { // then print response status
            console.log("response = ",response);            
        })
      }
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to send multiple image files in the response of JAXRS?
2. How to receive multiple files in ReactJS GET response?
3. How to display received files in ReactJS?
4. Please provide solution to this issue.

Comment: Maybe just Base64 encode the images and send them as JSON strings. You can decode it on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any example code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36492084/2587435

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21227078/2587435