# How to display an blob image received from database using Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-mvc, base64

Good day dear community. I got a problem when trying to display received image from MySQL via Base64. Image uploaded and stored on DB without a problems.

My model class:

```
@Entity
public class PostModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column (name = "title")
private String title;

@Column (name = "preview")
private String preview;

@Column (name = "content")
private String content;

@Column (name = "views")
private int views;

@Lob
@Column (name = "image")
private byte[] image;

//Getters and setters
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/blog/{id}")
    public String showContent(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) throws 
    UnsupportedEncodingException {
    
    if (!postRepository.existsById(id)) {
        return "redirect:/post_not_exist";
    }
    Optional<PostModel> post = postRepository.findById(id);
    ArrayList<PostModel> content = new ArrayList<>();
    post.ifPresent(content::add);
    model.addAttribute("post", content);

    
    byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(post.get().getImage());
    String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
    model.addAttribute("contentImage", base64Encoded );
    return "post_content";
    }
```

And HTML tag:

```
   <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${contentImage}"/>
```

For result, I have this: [The problem element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcWEV.png)

What I doing wrong?

Good wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the view with `modelAndView.addObject("contentImage",base64Encoded );` and also import `ModelAndView` and change your method to `ModelAndView` and instance the class `ModelAndView` with `ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view");` like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

```
@GetMapping("/blog/{id}")

public ModelAndView showContent(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) throws 
UnsupportedEncodingException {

if (!postRepository.existsById(id)) {
    return "redirect:/post_not_exist";
}
Optional<PostModel> post = postRepository.findById(id);
ArrayList<PostModel> content = new ArrayList<>();
post.ifPresent(content::add);
model.addAttribute("post", content);


byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(post.get().getImage());
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
model.addAttribute("contentImage", base64Encoded );

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("view");
modelAndView.addObject("contentImage",base64Encoded );
return modelAndView;

}
```

With this, you can call the variables returned from `modelAndView and you can add more values if you want.

Here is a link that can help you with this topic with some examples: [ModelAndView](https://zetcode.com/spring/modelandview/)

Comment: Sorry, but my problem still wasn't solved... I flagged your anwser as solution, I got base64 image and trying to set this in HTML page : `<img th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${contentImage}}">` . But It is not displaying and returns: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,cHJlc2lkZW50LmpwZw==">` I saw so many similar cases from other programmers, this doesn,t works. Please, if you know this, can you help me? I wanna to pay reputation for you, but I still can't...

Comment: are you sure that's the right image in base64 format? is because I tested that image and doesn't work. can you add the image into a comment?

Comment: Check this article to convert your image in bytes to base64. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492084/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-string-in-java

Comment: Yes! All Right! Your advice Is helped me! :) I found a problem when uploading image to DB, the image was uploaded not correctly and I have wrong binary code. Thank You so much! Sorry, but I am still beginner...